# Plural form of compound words

Tags: plurales, morfología, vocabulario

The plural form of compound words in Spanish is not an easy matter. If the compound word already has its final element in plural form, then the plural form is the same as the singular one: for example, *el cortaúñas / los cortaúñas*. Otherwise, there seems to be three different categories for compound words according as how they form their plural form:

1. By forming the plural form of the final element: *la antesala / las antesalas*.
2. By forming the plural form of the initial element: *el hijodalgo / los hijosdalgo*.
3. By forming the plural form of both elements: *el gentilhombre / los gentileshombres*.

Is there a general rule to know how to obtain the plural form for compound words? Of course, the case in which the singular and plural forms are the same is not interesting; I am interested in the other case, illustrated by the three examples above.

Comment: The preferred form for the plural of "gentilhombre" is "gentilhombres", as expected http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/SrvltGUIBusDPD?clave=gentilhombre&origen=RAE. I'd go always pluralizing the noun, as it works in all the examples I can think of. If there are two nouns (as in "zarzamora"), pluralize the last one.

Comment: @belisarius, that should be an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aunque existe la palabra independiente "ante" («*me presento **ante** vosotros para que me juzguéis*»), en el caso de "antesala" no es la unión de las palabras "ante" y "sala" sino que es la unión de elemento compositivo "ante-" y el sustantivo "sala".

**A** - Los elementos compositivos ("auto-", "tele-", "ante-", "anti-", "a-", etc.) son invariables: automóviles, teléfonos, antecapillas, antibélico, ateos, etc.

**B** - Los adjetivos compuestos por prefijo y sustantivo son invariables (faros antiniebla, máscara antigas, etc.)

Hasta aquí está claro pues lo dice la RAE, ahora daré un pequeño rodeo:

**C** - Las unidades léxicas formadas por dos sustantivos se construye el plural con el primer sustantivo dejando invariable el segundo: «explotó un **coche bomba** en la calle» se pluraliza a «explotaron varios **coches bomba** en la calle», «es inviable conducir por Madrid en **horas punta**», «el uso de **mujeres objeto** siempre es polémico en publicidad, pero nunca oí a alguien quejarse del uso de **hombres objeto**»

**D** - Las unidades léxicas formadas por sustantivo y adjetivo se pluraliza con el plural de ambas palabras.

**E** - "Algo" es un pronombre indefinido neutro tanto para género como para número.

---

**Mi opinión** (que nadie lo tome como si lo dijera la RAE), y por lo tanto solo es una mera opinión que puede ser errónea, es la siguiente:

**1** - Si algún día la unidad léxica "coche cama" por un uso frecuente se llega a convertir en la palabra "cochecama", entonces su plural sería problemático porque algunos hablantes lo pluralizarían de la forma habitual para todos los sustantivos ("tenemos dos cochecamas"), otros hablantes unirían la expresión original en plural ("tenemos dos cochescama") y otros hablantes optarían por hacer las dos cosas ("tenemos dos cochescamas")

Si dentro de unos siglos se admitiera la palabra "cochecama" y la RAE mantuviera su política de los últimos siglos de promover lo simple por delante de otros usos, entonces promovería el prural "cochecamas" admitiendo durante un tiempo la palabra "cochescamas".

"Gentilhombre" cuyo plural recomendado es "gentilhombres" y se admite "gentileshombres" sería un caso idéntico al que ocurriría en el hipotético caso de que la RAE admitiera la palabra "cochecama" con plural "cochecamas" (recomendado) y "cochescamas" (permitido)

**2** - «hijo de algo» antaño se contraía por el arcaísmo «hijo dalgo», y hoy en día usamos la palabra "hijodalgo". Como "algo" es invariable ante el plural, la expresión original era «hijos dalgo» y se respeta en la palabra "hijosdalgo"

---

En mi opinión, en las palabras compuestas SIEMPRE se construye el plural siguiendo la pauta habitual para el resto de sustantivos y adjetivos excepto:

1º Adjetivos compuestos por prefijo + sustantivo que permanecen invariables.

2º Sustantivos que se originan como contracción por un uso intensivo de una unidad léxica. En estas palabras su plural es el plural de la unidad léxica original (gentileshombres, hijosdalgo)

Comment: +1 this seems to be a good answer, although my spanish is not so superb that I did understand everything. Probably you get no upvotes because of the meta discussion? http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/86/we-shouldnt-allow-questions-in-spanglish. I think for basic questions on spanish grammar, english answers are the way to go, otherwise spanish learners might stop reading the whole answer at all with a lot of technical terms.

Comment: Nexus, gracias por tu completa y comentada respuesta.