# ¿Existe alguna otra palabra además de "hijodalgo" que forme el femenino y el plural en un sitio que no sea el final de la misma?

Tags: gramática, plurales, solicitud-de-término

En [otra pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/638/12637) se ha comentado la forma irregular que tiene la palabra *hijodalgo* de formar el femenino y el plural. [Según el DPD](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=hijodalgo):

> **hijodalgo**. 1. ‘Hidalgo’. El femenino es *hijadalgo*: *«Se entroniza,
>   entre almohadas y sobre los envoltorios del oro, la encumbradísima hijadalgo»* (Carrasquilla Marquesa [Col. 1928]). No son correctos los femeninos <strike>hijodalga</strike> e <strike>hijadalga</strike>.
>
> 2. El plural es *hijosdalgo* e *hijasdalgo*: *«No había reunión de hijosdalgo [...] donde no se sucediesen desde entonces los brindis»* (Fuentes Naranjo [Méx. 1993]); *«Y aquesa noble condesa / De moros captiva iría, / Y con muchas hijasdalgo, / Que están en su compañía»* (Sepúlveda Romances [Esp. 1580]). No son correctos los plurales <strike>hijo(s)dalgos</strike> e <strike>hija(s)dalgas</strike>.

Este caso me resulta muy curioso, dado que al contrario que otras palabras como *gentilhombre*, que admite como plural *gentileshombres*, pluralizando ambas partes de la palabra (aunque la forma recomendada sea *gentilhombres*), esta pluraliza solo la primera parte.

¿Existe alguna otra palabra en español que forme el plural (y el femenino) de esta forma?

Comment: [Cualesquiera](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BRgGL9X), aunque sólo para el plural

Comment: Acabo de encontrar un caso parecido al de "gentilhombre": "[ricohombre](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=ricohombre)" admite "ricoshombres" como plural y "ricahembra"/"ricashembras" como femenino.

Answer (score 6):

[**Cualquiera**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BRgGL9X)

> De *cual* y *quiera*, 3.ª pers. de sing. del pres. de subj. de *querer*<sup>1</sup>.
> Forma apocopada **cualquier** en aceps. 1 y 2; a veces no se apocopa en algunos lugares de Am. ante s. f.
> Pl. **cualesquiera** y **cualesquier** excepto en aceps. 8 y 9.

sería otro ejemplo de pluralización de la primera parte solo.

Answer (score 5):

Mirando un poquito hacia abajo en el diccionario aparecen estas dos, muy similares a *hijodalgo*:

> *hijaputa - hijoputa*

Pero no sé si el plural es *hijosputa* o *hijoputas*. No he encontrado alguna referencia que lo aclare y no es una palabra que se use en mi país.

Comment: Me consta que la respuesta es demasiado simple. Debe haber otros casos que no mencionen a los hijos, ojalá los encontremos.

Comment: Simple, pero válida al menos en la forma femenina. Para el plural creo que se usaría "hijoputas" más que "hijosputa".

Answer (score 3):

Existe una palabra muy vulgar, usada en ámbitos foreros, que encaja dentro de este patrón: ***melafo***.

Sin entrar en debates acerca de la idoneidad de su uso para referirse a una mujer, "melafo" es una contracción de "me la follo". Esto hace que haya surgido su equivalente masculino como "melofo".

Curiosamente, he comprobado que existen dos plurales de la palabra: *melafos* y *melasfo* (y sus variantes masculinas *melofos* y *melosfo*), el primero es ortográficamente coherente y el segundo es gramaticalmente coherente. Sin embargo, el plural *melasfo* no parece ser usado como plural del sustantivo *melafo* sino como tiempo verbal del hipotético verbo *melasfar*, como en *Melasfo a todas*. Igualmente, el plural *melafos* no parece ser usado para referirse a varias mujeres con la expresada cualidad, sino para referirse al propio hecho de referirse así a una mujer, como en la expresión *Gracias por vuestros melafos* (seguramente usada en tono sarcástico).

No incluyo enlaces, dejo las búsquedas en Google a vuestro criterio.

Answer (score 1):

| malculino | femenino |
| --- | --- |
| **m**adre | **p**adre |
| **m**adrastr**a** | **p**adrastr**o** |
| co**m**adre | com**p**adre |

Estas palabras son de distintas raíces indoeuropeas, pero en sus formas actuales castellanas tienen casi la misma ortografía y desde esta perspectiva forman el femenino de una manera irregular.

También hay las formas desusadas de tu ejemplo:

| malculino | femenino |
| --- | --- |
| [fij**a**dalgo](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=fijadalgo) | [fij**o**dalgo](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=fijodalgo) |