# ¿Existen palabras esdrújulas o llanas que acaben en "on"?

Tags: acentuación

A raiz de esta [pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/18812/existe-alguna-otra-palabra-adem%C3%A1s-de-hijodalgo-que-forme-el-femenino-y-el-plu) me puse a buscar y encontré unos pocos ejemplos de plurales irregulares: hijosdalgo que aparece en la pregunta de Carlos, cualesquiera, quienesquiera y el más extraño de todos, hipérbatos, plural de hipérbaton.

Mi primera duda fue de donde salía esa forma ¿por qué no se dice hiperbatones o hipérbatones? Aunque buscando algo más ví que también se dice *hipérbato* por lo que tiene más sentido. Pero la pregunta es otra, pensando en palabras que teminan en *on* no he sido capaz de encontrar ninguna otra que no sea aguda de 30 o más que se me han ocurrido en un rato. ¿Existe alguna palabra terminada en *on* aparte de hipérbaton que no sea aguda?

Comment: Sobre lo de "hipérbatones", como dijo la RAE y descubrimos en [esta pregunta](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/18445/12637), no existen en español sustantivos sobresdrújulos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Acromion
- Aron
- Asíndeton
- Bádminton
- Beicon
- Bustrofedon
- Canon
- Claxon
- Colon
- Dalton
- Épsilon
- Eslalon
- Fitoplancton
- ...

Vete al [buscador de la RAE](http://dle.rae.es/). Pulsa en el desplegable a la izquierda del cuadro de búsqueda (donde pone "por palabras"), cámbialo por "termina en" y escribe "on" en el recuadro de búsqueda. Mucha gente desconoce que lo de la izquierda es un desplegable, la verdad es que no parece uno.

Comment: Cierto, no sabia que era un desplegable. Me imaginaba que habría algunas palabras pero no podía encontrarlas así de memoria, ahora que veo tus ejemplos algunas como colon o canon son bastante comunes, otras son un poco más raras y desconocidas para mi.

Comment: @blonfu para ti y para cualquiera. La de _bustrofedon_ o _bustrófedon_ me ha encantado.

Comment: Sí, curiosa palabra por su sonoridad y significado. Y por cierto tiene toda la gama: bustrófedon, bustrofedon, bustrofedón.

Comment: También me ha sorprendido ese _bustrofedon_, y su origen no tiene desperdicio: http://etimologias.dechile.net/?bustrofedo.n

Answer (score 2):

Oxímoron al parecer en plural los oxímoron (sin modificación) o los oxímoros